# Вернуть исходную позицию анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект, который меняет свой scale в анимации, после animation.Stop(); анимация останавливается с тем размером, с которым в этот момент проигрывалась, можно как то сбросить объект в исходный размер после остановки анимации, без присвоения нужного размера объекта после остановки анимации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта два:

1. Переводить анимацию на первый кадр, и останавливать, тогда вы вернетесь в исходное состояние.

`var desired_play_time = 0.0;
    animation["MyAnimation"].time = desired_play_time;
    animation["MyAnimation"].speed = 0.0;
    animation.Play("MyAnimation");`

2. Писать скрипт который будет после остановки анимации восстанавливать требуемые значения из кода.